# Is there any spacecraft in Star Wars that doesn't have artificial gravity?

Tags: star-wars

I have never seen any scene in zero gravity or micro-gravity which makes me curious.

Does every spacecraft, pod, fighter, and shuttle in the universe get artificial gravity by design?

I am looking for canonical answers from films or officially copyrighted material owned by Lucasfilms (and Disney since 2015). Try to avoid fan fiction, or alternate universe novels and comics except as an aside to a canonical answer.

Comment: I wouldn't think that the single fighter cockpit style ships would bother having artificial gravity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To respond to the statement in the question: *"I have never seen any scene in zero gravity or micro-gravity?"* - there is a scene in the first / pilot episode of **[Star Wars Rebels: Spark of Rebellion](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels:_Spark_of_Rebellion)**, Sabine and Chopper disable the artificial gravity on a transport ship.

It is noted that this ship normally comes equipped with working artificial gravity.

[image: 23mn into the episode, Agent Kallus is affected by microgravity]

Comment: There are two other canon references to disabling artificial gravity listed in the sources here, but I don't have access to those resources, so I can't verify, thus not including them in the answer: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Artificial_gravity

Comment: Wow I didn't remember that! The ship did actually have AG I think.

Comment: @VogonPoet - it did have ag until it was turned off

Comment: This is clearly not a ship built without artificial gravity; it's a ship with the AG turned off.  Asker is looking for ships (of whatever size or purpose) built without AG.

Comment: OP needs to clarify the question in that case @ZeissIkon. OP states "I have never seen any scene in zero gravity or micro-gravity. Does every spacecraft, pod, fighter, and shuttle in the universe use artificial gravity?" My answer addresses both of these statements. 1) Here is a picture that lets OP see that this has happened within the requested canon. 2) in this case, the ship is **not** using artifical gravity. The fact that it can be enabled / disabled indicates that it is not an inherent / fundamental aspect of all ships...

Comment: ..it's an optional feature (granted, most, if not all that we have seen do use it) but the fact is implicit. During this scene, this instance answers the question title and question **as asked**. This ship does not have artifical gravity at this time

Comment: @NKCampbell Having an on-off switch (or equivalent) isn't related to having or not having the feature.  Your answer doesn't do anything to show all SW ships have AG, nor does it show one that was built without it.

Comment: the question doesn't ask that though - like I said - AS ASKED, I answer the question and it can be argued that since they seem to be built WITH IT, they can be built without @ZeissIkon - OP can edit the question to be more clear. OP was even asked a clarifying question by another user and did not respond

Comment: "Does every spacecraft, pod, fighter, and shuttle in the universe use artificial gravity?"  "Does my car use gasoline?"  Same kind of question -- yes, poorly worded, but it's aimed at design and intent, not damage or sabotage.  You address neither design nor intent.

Comment: that's your interpretation of the question - nowhere is that indicated @ZeissIkon
I do address design in my comments

Comment: "Have" is actually a design question. My car "has" headlights even when they're burnt out. Although I agree it is misused colloquially some times. I'm not speaking colloquially, for the record. That question would be "Does every craft have WORKING AG?" which is pedantic and would cost me a great deal of reputation :/

Comment: It won't cost you any repuation to ask the question properly for the answer you want. I edited it for you @VogonPoet

Comment: It looks weird. I was actually OK with what was coming across. I think "have" is self-explanatory. What exactly is your concern? I'll make the edit

Comment: @VogonPoet "by design" is a good edit. As my comments indicate though "have" is clearly not self-explanatory because my answer can be valid without further clarification. If AG is off, it does not "have" AG at the moment. If the question said "have an AG **device**" that would be a different matter. AG is a condition in the environment and it can be or not be at any given time. What you are **meaning** (but did not originally say) it seems, is if there are any ships that do not have the capability of producing a state of AG

Comment: OK we've butchered our language a bit but looking at this as I intended (as a bit of a stickler for proper grammar), if I tell you "I don't have cruise control" it actually only has one meaning. BUT, in "lazy english" I may have been saying "I don't have [operational] cruise control" or "I don't have [use of] cruise control" Here, "Cruise control" is being used as "an ability to control speed" instead of "an electronic device which controls speed." But when the object is "the ability", I am technically omitting some words. Take the sentence on its face, it only has the first meaning.

Comment: As I said, my question is not asking for anything to be assumed or inserted. It is what it is.

Comment: And I answered as "it is". I took it on it's face, directly. The ship, at that moment, did not have artifical gravity. See the little men floating around? How much more direct can it be? My answer was correct. Words have meaning. If you intend it to mean something different from what you wrote, write it properly (which we eventually did via the edit :) Don't downvote because you didn't write the question in such a way as to get the answers you wanted @VogonPoet

Comment: OK you win. "By design" should fix it. ...And I can't just shut up. "Are there any convection ovens that don't have heat?" Of course! The ones that are turned off! LOL! Just frame it in the "quality answer" perspective.